# Kinematics for tricycle drive robot

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, ros-noetic

I have a tricycle drive robot with propulsion and steering in the front wheel, and the rear wheels are fixed. I want to calculate the robot's steering angle and front wheel velocity from the twist message. I couldn't find anything related to this on Google. However, ChatGPT provided the following equations:

Steering angle:

```
theta = atan2(L * w, |V|)
```

Front-wheel velocity:

```
Vf = V / cos(theta)
```

- ​V is the linear velocity of the robot
- w is the angular  velocity of the robot
- L is the distance between front-wheel and rear wheels

Can anyone please confirm whether the above equations are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be ok, there is a similar implentation with ros2_controllers

- https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/blob/master/tricycle_controller/src/tricycle_controller.cpp#L636
- https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/blob/master/tricycle_controller/src/tricycle_controller.cpp#L652

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will test it on my AGV and post the result here.